# xsl:for-each loop with attribute matching with parameter

Tags: xslt, foreach

I've been trying to figure this our for a while, but no luck.

I have a for each loop specifically targeting to a node with specific attributes, but somehow the for each condition doesn't seem to work.

I have the following xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application-template xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <config>
        <env value="testing">
            <subEnv value="env">
                <group value="group2s">
                    <group value="group2as">
                        <prop value="group2Props">group2PropValues</prop>
                    </group>
                </group>
            </subEnv>
            <subEnv value="misc1">
                <group value="group2s">
                    <group value="group2as">
                        <prop value="group2Props">group2sPropValues</prop>
                    </group>
                </group>
                <group value="group2s1">
                    <group value="group2as1">
                        <prop value="group2Props">group2s1PropValues</prop>
                    </group>
                </group>
            </subEnv>
        </env>
        <env value="testingA">
            <subEnv value="env">
                <group value="test2">
                    <group value="test2a">
                        <group value="test2ab">
                            <prop value="group2Props">testingAGroup2PropValues</prop>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                </group>
            </subEnv>
        </env>
    </config>
</application-template>
```

with the following xsl

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <xsl:param name="inputEnv"/>
    <xsl:variable name="env" select="/application-template/config/env[@value=$inputEnv]"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="ou">
            <xsl:with-param name="subEnvPos" select="$env/subEnv"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="subEnvValue" select="$env/subEnv/@value"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="ou">
        <xsl:param name="subEnvPos"/>
        <xsl:param name="subEnvValue"/>

        <xsl:variable name="test" select="/application-template/config/env[@value=$inputEnv]/subEnv[@value=$subEnvValue]"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="$test/group">
            testing1:
            <xsl:value-of select="$test"/>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The param inputEnv is "testing" and the param $subEnvValue is "env".  The output I got is

testing1:group2PropValues
testing1:group2PropValues
testing1:group2PropValues
testing1:group2PropValues

But I want to just loop once since the the condition is to match the subenv node = $subEnvValue (which is "env").  The output I'm hoping for is

testing1:group2PropValues

Answer (score 1):

**I think that instead of your current code**:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="ou">
        <xsl:with-param name="subEnvPos"
           select="$env/subEnv"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="subEnvValue"
           select="$env/subEnv/@value"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

**you want something like this**:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="ou">
        <xsl:with-param name="subEnvPos"
           select="$env/subEnv[1]"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="subEnvValue"
           select="$env/subEnv[1]/@value"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

**With this modification, the complete XSLT code now is:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:param name="inputEnv" select="'testing'"/>

    <xsl:variable name="env" select=
    "/application-template/config/env[@value=$inputEnv]"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="ou">
            <xsl:with-param name="subEnvPos"
               select="$env/subEnv[1]"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="subEnvValue"
               select="$env/subEnv[1]/@value"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="ou">
        <xsl:param name="subEnvPos"/>
        <xsl:param name="subEnvValue"/>
        <xsl:variable name="test" select=
        "/application-template/config/env
                 [@value=$inputEnv]/subEnv[@value=$subEnvValue]"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$test/group">
testing1:
            <xsl:value-of select="$test"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and when applied to the provided XML document:**

```
<application-template xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <config>
        <env value="testing">
            <subEnv value="env">
                <group value="group2s">
                    <group value="group2as">
                        <group value="group2bs">
                            <prop value="group2Props">group2PropValues</prop>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                </group>
            </subEnv>
            <subEnv value="misc1">
                <group value="group2s">
                    <group value="group2as">
                        <group value="group2bs">
                            <prop value="group2Props">group2sPropValues</prop>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                </group>
                <group value="group2s1">
                    <group value="group2as1">
                        <group value="group2bs1">
                            <prop value="group2Props">group2s1PropValues</prop>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                </group>
            </subEnv>
            <subEnv value="misc2">
                <group value="group2sMisc2">
                    <group value="group2asMisc2">
                        <group value="group2bsMisc2">
                            <prop value="group2Props">group2PropValuesMisc2</prop>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                </group>
            </subEnv>
        </env>
    </config>
</application-template>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
testing1:
            group2PropValues
```

---

**Update**:

After the OP explained in a comment what he wants, here is a short and simple solution to the new problem:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:param name="vinputEnv" select="'testing'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*/env">
  <xsl:if test="@value = $vinputEnv">
    <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*[not(*)]">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('testing1: ', ., '&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the provided XML document (above), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
testing1: group2PropValues
testing1: group2sPropValues
testing1: group2s1PropValues
testing1: group2PropValuesMisc2
```

Comment: @user2387761, Please, *update* the question -- it is challenging to understand this comment.

Comment: sorry... I'm a newbie here and I'm trying to add more code to the comments but I couldn't seem to format the new code correctly.  So, I've updated the original XML.  I'm thinking of going one step further... that is to after the </xsl:for-each>, I like to go back into the ou template to process the next <subEnv>.  Also, the other thing I like to do is to given the "inputEnv", it will process the <env> node specified by $inputEnv (provided externally)

Comment: @user2387761, It would be best if you just explain well (in the question) what exactly you want to produce from the given XML document and what are the rules/constraints that the transformation should implement. I am 99% sure that once we know what you want to achieve, then a shorter, simpler and more elegant solution would be found.

Comment: thanks...  I'm looking for an output of, if inputEnv is "testing" testing1:group2PropValues testing1:group2sPropValues testing1:group2s1PropValues testing1:group2PropValuesMisc2.  If inputEnv is "testingA", the output will be testing1:testingAGroup2PropValues testing1:testingAGroup3PropValues.  The inputEnv is externally supplied at different times, so there could be different output based on inputEnv

Comment: @user2387761, No, You need to speak in terms of nodes, elements, structure -- such as: "I need to output the string value of every element named XYZ". Also, it may be good to provide a simpler and smaller example, that still demonstrates the problem.

Comment: ok... so... I like to output all the leaf nodes (named "prop") of each "subEnv" node given a specified attribute value for "env" node.  The "env" node attribute value is specified by the param $inputEnv